# MessageBox em VBA no Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Caros, boa tarde eu estou trabalhando em uma tabela dinâmica no excel e eu gostaria que quando fosse digitado o texto loja 10, ele exibisse um aviso que essa loja está indisponível, eu sei que preciso chamar uma messagebox porém não tenho ideia que outra estrutura necessito usar, podem auxiliar por favor?

Comment: eu só quero um exemplo de um código VBA pra quando for digitado "loja 10" em uma célula seja exibido uma messagebox... seria 'messagebox("loja está indisponível")' porém como eu coloco a condicional para a célula? essa é a dúvida que está me atormentando

Comment: Por que você não cria um combobox com as lojas possíveis? Seria muito mais fácil.

Comment: Qualquer célula de uma planilha?

Comment: sim sim, qualquer célula da planilha. @ReginaldoRigo o sistema é antigo de uma loja, teria que reformá-lo inteiro pra implementar de outra forma

Answer (score 0):

#### Inserir código de Evento

Utilizar o evento `Worksheet_Change`, em que este deverá ser colocado dentro da planilha em que os dados se encontram.
Por Exemplo, no meu caso foi em Planilha1:

[image: Planilha1]

#### Código para uma célula

O código é acionado toda vez que a planilha possui alguma alteração e possui uma condicional que se o valor é igual a "Loja 10".

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo CleanExit
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Target.Value = "Loja 10" Then
        Target.Value = ""
        MsgBox ("Não existe Loja 10!")
    End If

CleanExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

> Obs.: O evento pode causar lentidão, pois toda vez que uma célula for alterada. Este evento será acionado.